# Value Violates the Validation Rule

Tags: ms-access, validation, ms-access-2007

Everything works fine on my form,I always get the following message when I enter incorrect data in this particular field:

"*The value violates the validation rule for the field or record"*

I don't want the user to see this message. Unfortunately, it is not an error message..im not sure why i got this error since i have my Validation Rule and Text works fine

Comment: if i click "ok" on that message box it display my message box that display my Validation Text..all i want if i enter -ve value it should display my Text message box rather than that message..sorry if it not error but i want why it keeps popping up..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i need to make all my combo-box and Text-box for validation rule and validation text..the problem i only make for one text box that's why The *value violates the validation rule for the field or record* error keeps pops up

if i done for all text box and combo-box the Validation Text message box will display only without that error..